# Examining the function

Tags: real-analysis, graphing-functions

I am having trouble with this function

$$f(x) = e^{2x}(2x-1)+1$$

I found the domain, domain is $\mathbb R$, it is neither even nor odd function.

I found that $f(x)=0  \Leftrightarrow  x=0$, because it is obvious. I am having trouble with finding the sign of this function. That "+1" is making my life miserable. I can easily find the sign of $e^{2x}(2x-1)$, but what do I do with the constant?

Do I find the minimum of $e^{2x}(2x-1)$ and then add constant to it, and then check the sign?

That seems like too much work, considering that this function is actually a numerator of the first derivative of function that appeared in other graphing assignment. There has to be a better way...

The original graphing assignment was $$g(x)=\ln(e^{\frac{2x}{1-e^{2x}}})$$ You can ignore this one when writing the answer. I included it for the sake of context.

EDIT: By finding the "sign" of a function I mean finding the intervals for which $f(x)>0$ and $f(x)<0$.

Comment: What is the "sign" of a function?

Comment: What do you mean the sign of the function?

Comment: $f(0)=1$ so $0$ is no zero of $f$!

Comment: $$f(x)=\ln(e^{\frac{2x}{1-e^{2x}}})=?$$

Comment: @David Sorry guys, English is not my first language. I added the definition of what I mean by "sign" to the post.

Comment: @fleablood Added edit

Comment: If indeed f(x) = 0 iff x = 0 then all x < 0 f(x) will be the same sign and all x > 0 f(x) will be the same sign.

Comment: @MundronSchmidt Wrong. Read the full post, please.

Comment: (e^(2*0))*(2*0 - 1) + 1 = 0 guys....

Comment: You know that $\frac{df}{dx} > 0 \, \forall x$ so all you have to do is find a value $x_0$ such that $f(x_0) = 0$. Then it follows that $f(x) > 0 \, \forall x > x_0$.

Comment: Why is it obvious that f(x) = 0 then x = 0?

Comment: @fleablood Because f(0)=0... Please, check the post again.

Comment: Yes....  $x= 0 \implies f(x) = 0$ but how does $f(x) = 0 \implies x = 0$.  $\iff$ goes *TWO* ways.  One way is obvious.  The other way is not.

Comment: Notice if $x = 4$ then $x^2 -5x +  4 = 0$.  But if $x^2 -5x +  4 = 0$ that does not mean $x = 4$ as $x$ could also equal $1$.

Answer (score 2):

If you know there is only one zero of the function, then you can easily find the sign of the function by finding the value of a single point of the function on either side of the zero. Since the function is continuous, it will never cross the x-axis again!

Answer (score 2):

Since $f(x)$ is a continuous function, in order to find the intervals of positivity/negativity of $f(x)$ it is enough to understand where the zeroes of $f(x)$ lie. We have a little issue since
$$ e^{2x}(2x-1)+1 = 0 $$
is a trascendental equation, but $x=0$ is clearly a root, and actually a double root, since $f'(0)=0$.
Due to $f'(x)=4x e^{2x}$, we have that $f$ is increasing on $\mathbb{R}^+$ and decreasing on $\mathbb{R}^-$. It follows that $f(x)$ is always positive on $\mathbb{R}\setminus\{0\}$.

Answer (score 2):

What are the roots of $f(x)$?  As $f$ is continuous its positive and negative intervals will be between the roots.

You say it is obvious that $f(x) = 0 \iff x = 0$.  I that case as $f(-1) = \frac 1{e^2}(-3) + 1 > -\frac 34 + 1 > 0$ then for $x \in (-\infty, 0); f(x) > 0$.  And as $f(1) > 0$ then for $x \in (0,\infty); f(x) > 0$.

But I don't see that it is obvious that $f(x) =0 \implies x=0$.

$e^{2x}(2x - 1) + 1 = 0 \implies$

$e^{2x} = -\frac 1{2x-1}$  As $e^{2x} > 0$ then $ x < 1/2$. For $x < 1/2$, $-\frac 1{2x-1}$ is decreasing and $e^{2x}$ is increasing so there is only one solution and it is $x=0$.

So we are done.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation. 

Can you please, be a bit more detailed **why** the **x=0** is only zero-point of the function? You can see it when you plug in **x=0** in the function, but how can i find it if it weren't easy to spot? One side of equation being always positive, and the other being positive and negative is kind of confusing to me... Perhaps, can you give me a link to some literature? Thanks a lot.

Comment: Intermediate value theorem.  If f(k) > 0 than f(j) < 0 then f must *cross* the x axis somewhere between k and j.  But if there is only one root that is the only place it can cross.  So if we know there is only one root at x = 0 and f(-1) > 0.  Then all f(x);x < 0 must be positive because there is no place for f to cross the x-axis.  Same for f(1) > 0.  ***BUT*** and it is a ***HUGE*** "but",  we have to prove that $x =0$ is the ***ONLY*** root.

Comment: e^(2x)(2x−1)+1=0 I meant this one... What I'm asking is how to find the root of this.