# Finding a root of transcendental equation

Tags: real-analysis, transcendental-equations

I am having a problem with the following equation $$e^{2x}(2x−1)+1=0$$

By trial and error, you can see that the root is $x=0$, but how can I actually find it?

$$e^{2x}=\frac{-1}{2x-1}$$

As we can see, $e^{2x} > 0,  \forall x \in \Re$, but $\frac{-1}{2x-1} > 0 , x \in (-\infty,\frac{1}{2})$, and $\frac{-1}{2x-1}<0, x\in(\frac{1}{2},\infty)$.

When the $x\to-\infty$, LHS is decreasing, and RHS is increasing, but when $x\to\infty$ LHS is increasing, and RHS is decreasing. How can I find the root of this equation? It is clear that it has a root, because one can easily find two points where in one function is positive, and in the other one it is negative.

Comment: I don*t think that you can get an explicit form for the root. You have to use an approximation.

Comment: @Shocky2 This is a little bit unclear, but I'm assuming that your question is "how can I arrive at the answer without trial and error"? Is this correct?

Comment: It has already been shown in your previous question (https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2342089/examining-the-function) that the only real root is $x=0$. Did you care to read the proposed answers?

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio Yes, for the matter of fact, I did... But this kind of question was brought up a few more times in my math learning, and also, I didn't get an explicit answer to my question. Some people even wrote stuff without first reading through the entire question. Kind of rude.

Comment: @Shocky2: you did not get an explict answer? What did you need more explicit than *the given function is everywhere positive except that at the origin* ?

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio What to do when that problem comes up again, and the root is not obvious for the method of trail and error. That's why I asked this question.

Comment: That is a different question from the question you are proposing here.

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio Excuse my ignorance. If you could be kind enough, I would be very grateful to you for answering my intended question. I didn't know how to formulate it.

Comment: For solving trascendental equations there are a good number of tailor-made numerical methods, usually based on Newton's method.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To solve 
$$e^{2x}(2x-1)+1=0$$
you will need to use the [Lambert-W Function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambert_W_function). You can read that article about it if you want to, but, to make a long story short, it is the inverse of 
$$y=xe^x$$
so that
$$W(xe^x)=x$$
and
$$W(x)e^{W(x)}=x$$
Using this info, you can transform your equation into
$$e^{2x}(1-2x)=1$$
Letting $k=1-2x$:
$$ke^{1-k}=1$$
$$-ke^{1-k}=-1$$
$$-ke^{-k}=\frac{1}{e}$$
and so, applying the Lambert $W$ function,
$$-k=W\bigg(-\frac{1}{e}\bigg)$$
and
$$2x-1=W\bigg(-\frac{1}{e}\bigg)$$
This value of the Lambert-W function is known to be (and, upon inspection, is obvious to be) $-1$, so we have
$$2x-1=-1$$
$$x=0$$
Does that answer your question? If not, please clarify what you meant and I will be happy to change my answer.